# Sweex 7.1 External USB Sound Card

Tags: 11.10, sound, usb

I have just bought the above sound card and it is recognised within Ubuntu 11.10 and produces sound using the SPDIF output to my surround reciever.

The problem is that I cannot get it to output anything more than stereo over the SPDIF. In sound settings I cannot set anything other than Digital Stereo (IEC958) Output.

The chipset is cm6206 but is recognised as a "CM106 Like" card.

How do I get 5.1 digital surround sound to work?

Since this is the output for my media centre in the lounge its important that the surround sound works. Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Alex

Comment: Not on the output tab but on the hardware tab, what profile have you there selected?

Answer (score 3):

Today I was tired of trying to resolve the exact same problem with the same sound card and guess what... I simply installed the `paprefs` package that adds to your tools `pulseaudio` preferences; I could then configure my card and voila!!!

Answer (score 1):

This chipset is fully supported by Ubuntu so you should be able to use without problems.

Try this:

Click the Speaker top right hand corner, click *'Sound preferences'*. Select the *'Hardware'* tab. In the drop down menu choose a *Profile* for your device that meets your speaker layout.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can activate the spdif output in the alsamixer. After that you get stereo sound out of your speakers.

Now you use your Video player (eg. vlc) and configure it to pass trough the sound.
With that the reviever gets the digital signal and is able to give you 5.1 sound.

vlc -> extra -> settings -> audio
choose Alsa-plugin
use spdif if possible
and choose your soundcard

worked for me and i hope for you too ;)

have fun
Alex